# After save (ctrl+s) Javascript file change all format

Tags: javascript, svn, intellij-idea, tortoisesvn, intellij-14

I am having a problem with intellij IDE community edition 14.03 version that i hope you can help me,

when i modify a javascript file (an small change like a space) looks like intellij is changing the format or something behind scenes because when i check with svn tortoise in **show differences as unified diff** option looks like i was changing all my file, removing all the lines and the adding them again with the new change(the space that i added).

note: i was modifying the same file with webstorm IDE and when i select the same option(show differences as unified diff), this is just modifying the line that i change. i dont know if is something in my setting or a bug.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after checking this problenm with intellij team, in the bug

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15304

We realize that the problem was due to .editorconfig file, we can work with .editconfig file to standarize the format of our files, doesn't matter what IDE are you working on, but in my case this file was getting my a headache, in my case the only thing that i need to do to solve my problem was remove does files in my project and everything is working fine now.

but i just wanna to mention that this file could solve a lot of our problems if our team work with differents IDEs

I am leaving the link about this if you are interested on it.
http://editorconfig.org/